# Rearranging systems of equation in terms of specific variables

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

For triangle $ABC$, let $P$ be a point inside the triangle.

I'm trying to determine equations for lengths $PA,PB,PC$ in terms of side lengths $AB,BC,CA$ & internal angles $∠APB,∠BPC,∠CPA$.

Let
$AB=d, BC=e, PC=f$

Let
$PA=x, PB=y, PC=z$

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaWfe.png)

I began with 3 sets of cos rule

$d^2 = x^2+y^2-2xy\cos{(D)}$

$e^2 = y^2+z^2-2yz\cos{(E)}$

$f^2 = z^2+x^2-2zx\cos{(F)}$

So we have equations for $d,e,f$ in terms of $x,y,z,D,E,F$.

I'm trying to solve the above for $x,y,z$ in terms of $d,e,f,D,E,F$

eg we have $d = f(x,y,D)$. But I'm trying to obtain $x = f(d,e,f,D,E,F)$

I've tried substitution on the above but it ends up a crazy mess... I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Apologies if I haven't used proper mathematical terminology..